# MongoDB: Find sets of documents that have same key value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm searching a collection based on some conditions:

```js
const orders = Order.find({ status: 'ACTIVE', isInFlux: true  });
```

Then as I loop through every one of those documents I search Orders again with:

```js
Order.find({ userId: order.userId, status: 'ACTIVE', inFlux: true })
```

Then I check to see if there are multiple orders belonging to this user that meet these conditions.

**Is there a way I can modify my query to get these documents in one shot without having to loop through all of them or possibly an aggregation that would help me?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're just trying to conditionally group orders by userID. This will probably do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "orders": {
        "$push": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$isInFlux",
                    true
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$status",
                    "active"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$$ROOT",
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/c8MGdZsjMlJ